# How do i prevent duplicate output among multiple, nested sql queries?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a query which lists 10 different items in a database.

Within this query, i have a nested query which, for each of items 1-10 listed above, finds related subcategories in another table.

So ultimately, 11 queries occur. 1 to iterate through the major categories, and the other 10 to query and output for each of those categories.

Problem is, collectively, they output duplicated values.

Since it is done over 10 queries, i cant use `DISTINCT`, because even if the output is distinct within its own query, it is not distinct in the overall group.

So how can i make sure that i multiquery list like this is unique? Does js or php have a built in function that can do such?

Comment: 1. Please list your query here with more detail information?

Comment: Mysql has subselects. Not that you should run gaga on those, but subselects are quite powerful. Also different things are imagineable, however you probably just have a broken design (because there is no design it sounds like, can happen, it's never too late to introduce that). So not only ask for some function that "solves" your issue, but outline which problem you're actually facing and be open to solve it at it's root-cause as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not really scaleable. You're already reaching large numbers of queries, imagine if you had 100 items...

Instead, consider creating a subquery within the original query, since this would allow you to only run one query and the MySQL engine can do all the crunch work more easily (since it knows what you're actually asking for).

Make use of `JOIN`s if possible, and pay close attention to indexes. I can't really help more without seeing some code, but this should help because `DISTINCT` would suddenly be usable again.

Comment: Sounds like the right track and without a specific question, I don't think you can expect a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a way to solve it without reworking my code. I just put the entire output from all queries into the same array using a non-resetting incremental $array[$i] and then used php's array_unique. :). PHP is a fantastically versatile language. My humble (noob) opinion.